# Liquibase contexts are ignored in a Spring Boot application

Tags: spring-boot, liquibase

I’ve defined below property in a Spring Boot (version 2.7.8) application:

spring.liquibase.contexts: test

And a change set has been annotated like this:

– changeset author:1 context:prod

When I run the Spring boot application the script annotated with context prod is executed.

Any idea why?

I am using Liquibase 4.21.0

Answer (score -2):

In Liquibase, contexts are used to control which change sets are executed based on the current context(s) specified. It allows you to selectively run specific change sets based on the context(s) set in the application configuration.

In your case, it seems that the Liquibase contexts are not being properly applied in your Spring Boot application. There could be a few reasons why this is happening:

Liquibase configuration: Double-check your Liquibase configuration to ensure that it is correctly set up to read the spring.liquibase.contexts property. Make sure you have the necessary dependencies and the configuration is being loaded correctly.

Configuration property format: Verify that the property spring.liquibase.contexts is specified correctly in your application's configuration file (e.g., application.properties or application.yml). It should be a comma-separated list of context names.

For example:

spring.liquibase.contexts=test
Change set annotations: Ensure that the change set annotation is properly defined with the correct context. Make sure the context attribute value matches the context(s) you want to associate with the change set.

For example:

kotlin

@ChangeSet(author = "1", context = "prod")
Compatibility issues: There might be compatibility issues between the version of Liquibase you are using (4.21.0) and Spring Boot (2.7.8). It's possible that a bug or a change in behavior is causing the contexts to be ignored. Consider checking the release notes or the issue tracker for both Liquibase and Spring Boot to see if there are any known issues related to context handling.

Debugging and logging: Enable debugging or detailed logging for Liquibase in your application to see if there are any relevant log messages indicating why the contexts are being ignored. This can provide valuable insights into the execution flow and help pinpoint the issue.

It's worth noting that Liquibase integration in Spring Boot usually works seamlessly, so if you've confirmed that your configuration and annotations are correct, it's possible there might be an underlying issue related to the specific versions you are using.

Comment: I've already reviewed everything you mentioned Bezolla

Comment: This appears likely to have been written (entirely or partially) by AI (e.g., ChatGPT). If you used an AI tool to assist with any answer, I would encourage you to delete it, as [posting of AI-generated content is banned here](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831). **Readers should review this answer carefully and critically, as AI-generated information often contains fundamental errors and misinformation.** If you observe quality issues and/or have reason to believe that this answer was AI-generated, please leave feedback accordingly. The moderation team can use your help to identify issues.